# Repercussions of applying U.K. standard visit visa more than 3 months before travel

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I was curious if the 3 month rule is strictly enforced for the standard visit visa to the U.K. I am an Indian passport and Canadian PR and I applied to the U.K. standard visit visa more than 3 months before my intended travel date. The VFS Global in Toronto accepted my application and said it won’t be grounds for rejection (might be grounds for delay) but now I am a bit worried. Travel is March 24th 2023 and application date is Nov 29th 2022.

I have held UK standard visitor visa previously and many other visas if that helps.

Comment: What three month rule?

Comment: @phoog Not sure if it’s a rule as such, but the 3 month limit is stated here https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question, the Visa was approved in a week. No delay either.